# Why does using my function as a parameter for another function cause an error? Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying, higher-order-functions

I have two functions:

```
f1 :: Bool -> Int
f1 x 
    | x == True     = 5
    | x == False    = 10

f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 x = x * 2
```

Since the output of f1 is the correct input for f2, how come

```
f2 f1 True
```

causes an error?

I didnt know what to tag so the tags might be inappropriate.

Comment: Try `f2 (f1 True)` or `f2 $ f1 True`.

Comment: @Jubobs  Could you give me an example where (f g) x is a well-formed expression, with f and g both being functions?

Comment: @Arthur `filter odd [1, 2, 3]` for example.

Comment: @Arthur Consider `doTwice f x = f (f x)` It has the type `(a->a)->a->a`. Then `(doTwice (\x -> x+1)) 3` is well formed.

Comment: @Cirdec Thanks, very helpful. What about and example where f . g x is a well formed expression?

Comment: `let f = head; g = filter; x = odd; in map (f . g x) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

Comment: @Arthur Now I'm convinced those are both homework questions. Here's a hint. If `(f g) x` is well formed, there must exist some function `h` such that `h . f g` is well formed.

Answer (score 4):

Function application is left-associative, so `f2 f1 True` is the same as `(f2 f1) True`, not `f2 (f1 True)`. `(f2 f1) True` is clearly mis-typed as the argument of `f2` has type `Int`, but `f1` has type `Bool -> Int`, not `Int`.